# node JS HTTP request does nothing using http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, tizen-web-app

I'm trying to send http post request using native node js http request.
I'm using the following code but nothing happens:

```
    var http = require('http');

    var options = {
      hostname: '192.168.1.134',
      port: '8082',
      path: '/api',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {'content-type': 'application/json',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache'}
    };

    callback = function(response)
    {
      var result = [];
      response.on('data', function (chunk)
      {
        result.push(chunk);
      });

      response.on('end', function ()
      {
        console.log("LOCAL END" + result);
      });
    }

    var req = http.request(options, callback);


    req.write(JSON.stringify(
    { 
        customer: 'customer',
        deviceIndicator: 'id',
        userId: 'id2',
        lastVersion: 999 
    }), 'utf8' , 
    function(data)
    {
        console.log('flushed: ' + data);
    });
    req.end();

    console.log(" - trying to post to example - done" );
```

But if i'm adding the following dummy calls i'm getting an answer from my local server as expected:

```
    var options1 = {
      hostname: 'www.google.com',
      port: '80',
      path: '/',
      headers: {'cache-control': 'no-cache'}
    };

    callback1 = function(response1) {
      var str = ''
      response1.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
      });

      response1.on('end', function () {
        console.log("GOOGLE END" + str);
      });
    }

    var req1 = http.request(options1, callback1);
    req1.end();

    console.log("sent to google - done");
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: can you add a on error block to see if it is throwing any error ?

Comment: Try adding a `Content-Length` header to your POST request.

Comment: Is there something listening on 192.168.1.134:8082? The second one works because you are calling www.google.com:80 and it obviously responds, you probably cannot reach anything at 192.168.1.134:8082

Comment: Did you add a `console.log()` inside `callback` to ensure that you at least get a response (before the response body starts)?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  My server is working fine. Tried to send a request using Chrome extension and it worked great. In addition,  when sending a request to Google server (either before my request or after my request)  I'm getting the response from my local server as expected. Server is reachable and working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure 192.168.1.134:8082 is reachable and responding (using a browser, curl or wget) then try adding a `content-length` header:

```
var http = require('http');

var payload = JSON.stringify({ 
  customer: 'customer',
  deviceIndicator: 'id',
  userId: 'id2',
  lastVersion: 999 
});

var options = {
  hostname: '192.168.1.134',
  port: 8082,
  path: '/api',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'content-length': Buffer.byteLength(payload), // <== here
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache'
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(response) {
  var result = [];

  response.on('data', function(chunk) {
    result.push(chunk);
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log('LOCAL END' + result);
  });
});

req.write(payload);
req.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I discovered that the problem was with the device itself which had some kind of problem.. 
When sent http request to a direct ip address nothing happened but when sent to an address that need dns server it is working...

Unfortunately, I don't have any additional info about this bug...